# Error : 14 UNAVAILABLE: DNS resolution failed on BloomRPC golang GRPC

Tags: go, grpc

I'm figuring out how I can test my golang project using Bloomrpc. I've turned on the backend server, client server and db server but an error pop up like this on Bloomrpc:

[image: the error]

Comment: you can check this [issue](https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc/issues/184)

Answer (score 0):

Am sure you found a solution already but just for the people like myself who may still run into same issues, here is what I have tried and has worked for me.

First off, you may want to ensure you remove the `http://` or `https://` before the url.

then, use `localhost:[portnumber]` or `127.0.0.1:[portnumber]` (if on local host of course)

Also check your console to ensure you are using the right port. If not sure, try all the ones you see there.

I did this and it worked great for me.

Here is a link for other solutions (same as shared by Rahmat Fathoni): https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc/issues/184